# How to make visio image clear even when you drag a corner to resize it small?

Tags: microsoft-visio, drawing, shapes

How do you draw clear shapes in Visio? I think it's related to resolution somehow. I tried to increases line with to 3-5 but still doesn't look good. I also tried to reduce the distance between lines and shapes but I saw some people can make the image small but still look very clear. Unfortunately I don't have these images here.

How can I make a high resolution image so it is still look good, clear even when I CTRL and corner handles in Visio to resize it to a smaller size.

[image]

Comment: Your diagram looks clear enough to me, except the resistor shapes look a bit off. Which version of Visio? Desktop on Online? Are these the built-in shapes?

Comment: @PaulHerber I use desktop, 2019 version. They aren't buit in shapes. I'm asking about a general way instead.